# Three-digit numbers with identical digits in the hundreds and ones places

Tags: combinatorics

How many three-digit numbers are there whose digits in the hundreds place and ones place are the same? (Assume that a nonzero digit is in the hundreds place.)

Please try to simplify the solution so that a child under 14 may understand this.  Also, it would help if you included a formula that *may* be reusable in similar circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

All the numbers are of the form $XYX$.  Note that $X$ can be $1 \to 9$.  For each of these $9$ cases the middle digit $Y$ can be any of ten digits, $0 \to 9$.

Thus there are $9 \cdot 10 = 90$ such numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather simple, so here is some advice on how to solve it. Consider the number of ways to get your statement to be true. How many ways can you get the ones and hundreds places to be the same? What are the possibilities for the tens place? To find the total number of possibilities, multiply the independent possibilities.

Comment: Thank you so much! In the future, also please try to include the formula or examples.